# Привязка маркера к радиусу или наоборот

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, можно ли в yandex картах сделать привязку радиуса к маркеру или наоборот. По аналогии (как пример Google maps)

`<http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/k6hVa/>`

Comment: [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/k6hVa/)

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно.
Грязный код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([[55.847, 37.6],10000]);

var circleCenter = myCircle.geometry.getCoordinates();
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);

var center = new ymaps.Placemark(circleCenter, {}, {draggable: true});
var edge = new ymaps.Placemark([55.847, 38.6], {}, {draggable: true});
var projection = myMap.options.get('projection');
var coordSystem = projection.getCoordSystem();
var distance = coordSystem.getDistance(edge.geometry.getCoordinates(), circleCenter);

myCircle.geometry.setRadius(distance);

center.events.add('geometrychange', function() {
  var coords = center.geometry.getCoordinates();
  var offset = [coords[0] - circleCenter[0], coords[1] - circleCenter[1]];
  var edgeCoords = edge.geometry.getCoordinates();
  edge.geometry.setCoordinates([edgeCoords[0] + offset[0], edgeCoords[1] + offset[1]]);
  myCircle.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
  circleCenter = coords;
});

edge.events.add('geometrychange', function() {
  var coords = edge.geometry.getCoordinates();
  var distance = coordSystem.getDistance(coords, circleCenter);
  myCircle.geometry.setRadius(distance);
})
myMap.geoObjects
.add(center).add(edge);
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/2rg540Lc/